# How to force a reset to factory defaults on a Logitech G600?

Tags: linux, logitech-mouse, factory-defaults

I bought a Logitech G600 MMO mouse a while ago, and it's always worked fine for me until very recently.

I have *no* idea what button or combination I pressed by accident while trying to clean it, but for some reason while in linux its DPI settings are stuck at the minimum setting, causing glacially slow movement, and all the buttons (but not the scroll wheel) are unresponsive.

If I reboot to Windows, the mouse works fine even before the logitech profile manager finishes starting, but when I reboot to linux afterwards the problem recurs.

Unplugging the mouse and plugging it back in has not helped; I'm guessing that it somehow messed up the default profile it uses when it has no specific instructions.

Is there a way to force a reset to factory defaults?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the exact same issue you described. It appears fixed after uninstalling and reinstalling the Logitech Gaming Software.